# How to check if a Localization Strings Table Exist

Tags: ios, macos, localization, internationalization

As in iOS we can have multiple `string` files [`Tables`] to separate `localization`.

Is there is a way to verify if the specific table exist in the bundle ??

**Use Case:**

I have pod which is used as a component in the main app. Now the component have many strings localization but i want to give this access to the main app as well to modify the strings or add other translations etc.

Currently i'm searching the main Bundle of the app if the specific path exist for `Table` if not then i read the key value for translation from the framework bundle.

**Code:**

```
let preferredLanguage = Bundle.main.preferredLocalizations.first!
let pathForTable = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "MyTableName",
                                ofType: ".strings",
                                inDirectory: "\(preferredLanguage).lproj")
```

So in the case above if `pathForTable` is `nil` then i read the strings from `Framework-Bundle` otherwise i use the main bundle to read the strings.

```
NSLocalizedString("mykey",
              tableName: "MyTableName",
              bundle: Bundle.main,
              value: "",
              comment: "")
```

**Is there a better way to find if a specific table exists ?**